# WSO2 change localhost - ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ssl, wso2

I'm using WSO2 6.1.0 and the browser find a valid certificate in my Carbon url
https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp
When I change the name of localhost, according this url https://medium.com/@igunawardana/how-to-change-hostname-in-wso2-is-with-self-signed-certificate-ea547605e015, my browsers ( Chrome and Edge ) don't find a valid certificate.
Some ideas?
Sergio

Comment: Where did this certificate come from? Who created it, who signed it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check new certificate is properly imported into the server's keystore and that you're using the correct keystore with the WSO2 server configuration.
2. Verify that the certificate is correctly generated with the new hostname as the CN or is included in the SAN field if you're using that.
3. Browsers sometimes cache SSL certificates, so try clearing your browser's cache or try accessing the server using an incognito window.